# Excel VBA combining results from multiple checkboxes into single worksheet cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Userform frame containing 20 checkboxes, each checkbox represents a different coloured shirt.

When a user makes their checkbox selection/s, I'd like the results (the caption, not true/false) to end up in a single cell (column 8) of the active row, separated by a comma.

I'm a newbie at VBA coding and learning on the fly - can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit1:** Removed line continuation `_` on `If statement`.

Create a sub routine to check all the `Checkboxes` and pass the data to the selected cell.
 Try something like this:

```
Private Sub GetSelection()

    Dim c As MSForms.Control
    Dim cbk As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim sel As String


    For Each c In Me.Controls '/* Iterate all controls */
        If TypeOf c Is MSForms.CheckBox Then '/* check if it is a checkbox */
            Set cbk = c '/* Set as Checkbox to get the caption property */
            If cbk Then '/* Check value, get caption if true */
                If sel = "" Then 
                    sel = cbk.Caption 
                Else 
                    sel = sel & "," & cbk.Caption
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    '/* Transfer currently selected values in desired cell */
    Sheet1.Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value2 = sel '/* Used H for column 8 */

End Sub
```

Then all you need to do is call this sub routine in all your `CheckBox_Click` event.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    GetSelection

End Sub
```

Comment: That's nearly got me there, thanks so much! I just get a syntax error at
`If cbk Then _ `

I'm sure the answer must be staring me in the face!!

Comment: @hadtobe not sure what sysntax error you, got I run it and it's fine. Nonetheless, you can try completing the `If statement`.